# Required Dependencies for Redistribution of pure C (NOT C++) Library

Tags: c, windows, c99, software-distribution

### Background:

I am currently writing a `.dll` library using Visual C **(NOT C++)** which intends to provide performance-optimized functionalities for other applications. **All** functions in this library fulfill the following requirements:

- They operate purely on built-in primitive types (`int`, `long long`, etc.), pointers to these types, or self-defined `struct`s which in turn are comprised of these types.
- **No** code segment relies on external code or libraries - not even on `malloc` or `free`. I do not call any functions which I have not written myself (I even rewrote functions like `abs` as inline assembly code to avoid any external function calls).

Furthermore:

- The library has no external dependencies
- The code does not have any `#include ...`-statements
- The library is written in pure C (conforming the C99 standard - apart from the `__declspec(dllexport)`-statement decorating some of the written functions)

### Question:

- What are the dependencies needed for redeploying/redistributing this specific library?
  I think that I do not need the MSVC runtime as I do not use any external types, functions, or dependencies, am I correct?

Assuming my previous assumptions are incorrect, which parts of the MSVC runtime do I need to include/redistribute?

Comment: Are there any `#include <...>` lines in your code (where the `...` is a system header)? If so, then you *are* potentially using the VC run-time library. Even if there aren't any such headers, you *may* still have code that calls the RTL.

Comment: Nope, I do not have any includes. Furthermore, I do not call any function, which I do not have written myself (including exp, abs, min, max, ...)

Comment: You might find https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies useful.

Comment: Don't guess, verify.  Start the developer command prompt and run dumpbin.exe /imports foo.dll.  You'll get a list of all imported functions, grouped by the runtime dll they are expected to be imported from.

Comment: Visual C++ is the product name, even if you are compiling C code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual C++ is likely to pull in dependencies by default even for simple code (64-bit multiply/divide/shift when generating 32-bit code etc). If it turns out you need some of the features it provides then you have to statically link the C run-time library (`/MT`).

You can also force it to not depend on anything. Compile with something like `/O1 /GR- /GS- /GL /EHscr- /LD /Zl /link /NODEFAULTLIB /OPT:REF /OPT:ICF=9 kernel32.lib user32.lib`.

`/Zl` prevents you from using `DllMain` and if you actually need it you have to use `DllMainCRTStartup` instead. You might have to play around with the combinations of `/Zl`, `/LD`, `/MT` and `/MD` to find your sweet spot.

Use [Dependency Walker](https://dependencywalker.com/) to verify that you are not linking to any `*crt*`/`*vc*` .dlls...